# How to find a index of element for it's grand parent or parents of any..?

Tags: jquery

In my form, I have number of checkboxes, it's immediate parent is label element. So, while I get the index number it gives as 0 always.

so, how can I get the index number of from element? so I will get the index number of checkbox for it's grand parent of "form"?

this is my try: not woking:

```
    $("form").on("click", ":checkbox", function () {
        console.log($(this).index($("form")));
    });
```

Comment: `$("from")` does not look right. Do you have an element with tagName `<from>`?

Comment: @techfoobar: I think he meant `form`.

Comment: @Mr_Green why would he need the prefix?

Comment: @user1 if it is `from` but not `form`.

Comment: by typo issue.. sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var checkboxes = $('form').find('input:checkbox');
checkboxes.click(function() { 
    var selectedIndex = checkboxes.index($(this)); 
    console.log(selectedIndex); 

});
```

Here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/vvu4Z/)

Comment: yes, i got. the idea is while i load the page, some of the checkboxes are loaded as checked, when user turn off/on the status, i need to update to server... do you have any short approach to do this..?

Comment: Yeah, that can be easily done through an AJAX request, however I think that will need a new question as it is out of the scope of this one, if you think this was useful please consider upvoting and accepting so it remains useful for other users :) and as per your new requeriment you can post a new question amd we will help you with that one :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just need the index of the parent label:

```
$(this).parent().index()
```

Comment: If the parent label is not a direct child of the `<form>` this can have issues as well.

Comment: @techfoobar - True, but the question said the label _was_ a direct child (because it said the form was the grandparent of the checkbox). But I happily admit it can still have issues if there are other controls in the form besides just (label-wrapped) checkboxes.